# Прикрутить клиентский сертификат p12

Tags: python

Использую модуль `Requests` для `Python`, но необходимо прикрутить сертификат клиентский p12. Каким образом это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю документацию (сам не делал такого никогда), то надо при создании `Request` передать ему [параметр `cert`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Request) с сертификатом.

Семантика параметра, увы, не документирована. Можно или попробовать методом научного тыка или посмотреть в код. Но, по крайней мере, у [`Session.request`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.request) сказано, что:

> **cert** – (optional) if String, path to ssl client cert file (.pem). If Tuple, (‘cert’, ‘key’) pair.

И, подозреваю, что в других местах она такая же.

Между PKCS#12 и PEM можно преобразовать используя что-то в духе «`openssl pkcs12 -in bundle.p12 -out file.pem -nodes -clcerts`»